# Multiple NSTimers Xcode 6 Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I am increasing the y value of a `CGPoint` a certain amount per second. To do this I am using an `NSTimer` that fires at a certain function that increases the y value. The problem is that I am increasing the y value every time the user touches the display. I noticed that every time somebody tapped, there were multiple timers firing, and therefore increasing the y value more than wanted. So how do I remove previous NSTimers and only use the last one?

My current `NSTimer` setup

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var timer: NSTimer?
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

There is more to my code, but this the the basic `NSTimer` setup that fires at "update" which does the y value increasing.

I tried doing `timer.invalidate()` but this just made nothing work, and the timer would not restart

Comment: "and the timer would not restart" Of course. An invalidated timer cannot be reused; it is dead forever.

Comment: Isn't this just some kind of animation? A timer is the worst possible way to do animation. If you want to animate, use actual animation! It's built right into iOS.

Comment: Ok sure. How would I "animate" increasing a CGPoint y value by a certain amount per second?

Comment: That is just acceleration you are describing. It isn't hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is every time user taped,you have create a `NSTimer` instance,and you didn't remove the last  `NSTimer instance,so every created instance it run in runloop.

solution 1:

```
    var timer: NSTimer!
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if(timer == nil) {
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
```

solution 2:

```
    var timer: NSTimer!
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if(timer != nil) {
            timer.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

By the way: I don't think use `NSTimer` is a good way to animate object,use core animation instead.

Comment: Dude, THANK YOU! Used solution 2, and works perfectly. Still learning swift so every question that is solved helps! Hopefully this also solves the problem for other people who have a similar question

Comment: By the way, how would you use core animation to solve this problem? Good to know also